# Whats the problem with the media queries here?

Tags: css, media-queries, css-grid

Can anyone help me out with the media query issue where I've got stuck for days already.

It seems that everything is fine. I've even checked the same layout on codepen just to check myself but it works there, and doesn't work in the project.

that's my meta I usually use

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
```

```
@mixin grid-wrapper($fr, $width: 70%, $gap: 15px) {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat($fr, 1fr);
    gap: $gap;
    padding: 0 $gap;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: $width;
    @content;
}
```

mobile css - basement

```
#advantages {
    position: relative;
    @include grid-wrapper(12, 100%);

    h3 {
        grid-column: 1/13;
    }

    .adv-wrapper {
        grid-column: 1/13;

        div {
            position: relative;
            grid-column: span 12;
    }
}
```

```
@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
    #advantages {
        h3 {
            font-size: 1.5em;
        }

        .adv-wrapper {
            grid-column: 2/12;
            justify-self: center;
        }
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 679px) {
    #advantages {

        h3 {
            grid-column: 1/13;
        }

        .adv-wrapper {
            grid-column: 1/13;

            div {
                grid-column: span 4;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the last media query (679) span doesn't work. And I've got many similar circumstances when medias don't work.

I hope you can help me figure out the issue...

Comment: could you link also your codepen to see your issue in live / rendered style ?

Comment: @G-Cyrillus on codepen it works fine. I can give you the link to my repo if it helps

Comment: no need for me, but if you wich for others. Looks like a different setting or code between your codepen and code. (diiferent library version, css overwritten, ..)

Comment: @G-Cyrillus I’m slimming over the code and I clearly see that it should work but it refuses to ‍♂️ can it be the issue with webpack and the way it works with CSS and SASS?

Comment: There seems to be no problem with the code, so any details about your project that would matter will definitely help with answering the question.